# Iterating through items in a PivotTable column

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My loop doesn't work when the data field for a given row and column is empty.
The relevant code is as follows -

```
For Each PivotItem In PvtTbl.RowFields("Agent").PivotItems
    rw = rw + 1
        If PvtTbl.GetPivotData("PRD", "Agent", PivotItem.Name, "CT1", "IB") = 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(16, rw).Value = 0
         Else
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(16, rw).Value = PvtTbl.GetPivotData("PRD", "Agent", PivotItem.Name, "CT1", "IB")
         End If
Next PivotItem
```

The error I get is:

> Run-time error 1004/"Application-defined or Object-defined error"

I've tried "ISERROR" instead of setting the offending line to zero, but neither works.

Answer (score 0):

That no doubt happens because there is some combination of PvtTbl.GetPivotData("PRD", "Agent", PivotItem.Name, "CT1", "IB") that does not exist in your PivotTable. So you would need to check to see if that returns an error, and then handle it accordingly.

That said, it seems strange to me that you would want to do this via iteration in the first place. Why not just directly check if the thing in the DataField is zero or not? Or why not use the GETPIVOTDATA formula in the worksheet cells concerned?

Can you elaborate further about what you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: I mean, I've already stated that it is because of what you just said. My question is precisely HOW to, as you say, handle it without changing the table itself.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm trying to automatically generate a chart that shows agents' counts of PRD, both CT1, IB, CT2, and OB, whether they necessarily have tickets that fit those criteria or not. There should be a way to do this, I don't understand why it would return an error rather than just a 0 for an empty column and full row field.

Comment: Can't you just create a PivotChart that directly shows this, using no VBA whatsoever? Iterating through the PivotItems collection in order to get information about a data field is a very indirect way of doing whatever it is you're doing. If you're doing this because you want seperate charts for each agent, then you should check out the Show Report Filter Pages functionality, which produces seperate reports for each of the items in a particular field. See http://www.contextures.com/Excel-Pivot-Table-Report-Filters.html

Comment: Re your comment " I don't understand why it would return an error rather than just a 0 for an empty column and full row field"...that's because the  PivotTable simply does not have a value for the combination that you're asking for. It would be bad programming on MS's behalf if it returned a zero (which is a number) when there was actually no such combination.

Comment: By "chart" I didn't mean visualization such as a PivotChart; I just meant an arrangement of the same numbers in a different format. I need to keep doing this for work and I'm trying to automate it, hence the use of VBA.
As for "the PivotTable simply does not have that value and it would be bad programming to return any value," you're incorrect, as this screenshot (http://i62.tinypic.com/16i9pn8.png) of the same GETPIVOTDATA operation shows outside of the VBA editor context.

Comment: Can't you just use the worksheet function GETPIVOTDATA to give you an arrangement of the same numbers in a different format? Can you elaborate why you need VBA? 

No I'm not incorrect about the error. Rather, you have not understood me. Your code iterates through each Agent and asks for the value where the CT1 field = "IB". But for agents C and D, there IS no data where CT1 = "IB". Again, the PivotTable simply does not have a value for the combination that you're asking for.